# How do I make an object pointed? ( not too pointed but slightly thinner if that makes sense )

Tags: mesh, objects

I'm making a model of horns, but I used a plane to make the model. I used the solidifier and subdivision modifier. Any way I can make it pointed??
[image: i need the top to be more pointed]

[image: reference i used:]

Answer (score 2):

You can apply the modifiers, select the tip, enable the *Proportional Editing* option and scale down:

[image]

If for some reason you don't want to apply the modifiers and you want to stay non-destructive, you can create a kind of cage mesh around your horn, and give your horn a *Mesh Deform* modifier with this cage as *Object*, click on *Bind*, deform the cage:

[image]